# Chart.js only showing two datapoints in the middle of the data

Tags: chart.js

I could not get it going with code snippet so here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/akmiecik/v562aghf/18/

Why is this only showing the two datapoints from the middle of the data?  I tried deleting all points before and got nothing, same with all datapoints after.

```js
var dates = ["10/21/22", "10/24/22", "10/27/22", "10/28/22", "10/31/22", "11/03/22", "11/14/22", "11/26/22", "11/26/22", "11/28/22", "11/28/22", "11/30/22", "12/01/22", "12/02/22", "12/06/22", "12/07/22", "12/08/22", "12/09/22", "12/12/22", "12/13/22", "12/16/22", "12/21/22", "12/28/22", "01/10/23", "01/12/23", "01/13/23", "01/16/23", "01/17/23", "01/19/23", "01/21/23", "01/24/23", "01/26/23", "01/30/23", "02/04/23", "02/06/23", "02/08/23", "02/09/23", "02/14/23", "02/10/23", "02/13/23", "02/15/23", "02/16/23", "02/17/23", "02/21/23", "02/24/23", "02/27/23"];
var lap_ave = ["1:02", "1:04", "1:00", "1:01", "1:02", "1:01", "1:03", "1:03", "1:03", "0:59", "0:59", "1:01", "1:02", "1:01", "1:00", "1:00", "1:00", "1:00", "0:59", "00:58", "01:02", "01:04", "01:00", "01:02", "1.01", "1.04", "01:03.1000", "01:00.2188", "01:01.5862", "01:01.4516", "00:57.8621", "01:00.6129", "01:01.1290", "01:00.6563", "01:00.5000", "01:00.0909", "00:59.0294", "00:59.0294", "00:59.7059", "00:59.0000", "00:59.7000", "00:59.6757", "00:58.3125", "00:59.4118", "00:58.8056", "00:58.9459"]; 
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Lap Average',
          data: lap_ave,
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('theChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Comment: Why are you using ChartJS `2.9.3`?

Comment: No reason.  Just copied that from a different site I have.

Comment: I'd recommend using the latest version. But your issue is probably because your data does not match.

Comment: what do you mean by match?  Changing version did not affect outcome.

Comment: The formats don't match, they should!

Comment: I was about to suggest a simple function that would parse your data to seconds, but I  am not sure what do "1.01" and "1.04" mean. Is it really 1.01 minutes and 1.04 minutes, or is it a mistaken output and should actually be 1:01 (that is 1 minute and 1 second) and 1:04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are inconsistencies in the data you're passing. Some of the lap_ave's are "#.##" while others are "#:#.##"

If you change the last value in the fiddle below to "1.03", you'll see the third data point show up on the graph.

```
var dates = ["01/12/23", "01/13/23", "01/16/23"];
var lap_ave = ["1.01", "1.04", "01:03.1000"];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q0a23j4z/

Comment: I went into the database and changed all lap averages to seconds (eg. 1:03 = 63 seconds).  That did the trick.  https://jsfiddle.net/akmiecik/v562aghf/30/  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You provide strings for your data array. Chart.js expects numbers for the y axis. You can fix this by setting your y axis to a category scale and provide a labels array with a valid lap times.

But the easyest solution would be for you to transform the `minute:seconds` format to only seconds and use that in combination with a custom tick callback